# Python, SFTP connection with SSH - Ed25519 key

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I've a lot of issues with conection to my FTP. The server I use does not support TLS witch was the case with previous server. Instead it uses SSH with Ed25519.

**Step 1**

I tried to log to my FTP with PUTTY. Then I got a popup with a fingerprint, clicked 'Yes' and copypasted 'hostkey' data from Windows registry.

**Step 2**

I've hardcoded it.

**Errors**

The first trown error was `Incorrect padding` even when hostkey was divisible by 3. The numbers of chars in hostkey I pasted is 132. It was so easy to connect with ftplib.FTP_TLS.

**What I need**

Check my code if the way I try to use is correct. I attach my code below. After almost two days I give up. I couldn't find any example that utilize logging with ed25519 key.

**Code**

```
import pysftp as sftp
import paramiko
from base64 import decodebytes

myHostname = ""
myUsername = ""
myPassword = ""

key = b'0x2994....,0xe4fb.....'
print(len(key), len(key)%4, len(key)%3)

key = paramiko.ed25519key.Ed25519Key(data=decodebytes(key).hex())

cnopts = sftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys.add(myHostname, 'ssh-ed25519', key)

print('TYPE CNOPTS', cnopts, type(cnopts), cnopts.__dict__['hostkeys'].__dict__)

def ftp_connect():
    try:
        ftp = sftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts)

    except Exception as ex:
        print('CONN EX', ex)
    else:
        return ftp

ftp_connect()
```

Comment: Paramiko supports OpenSSH key format only, please convert  Putty key to OpenSSH key using PuTTYgen (Conversions > Export OpenSSH key), as  a side note Ed25519 key support was added to OpenSSH in version 6.5.

Comment: I tried to do this before the post. The problem was that puttygen requires `.ppk` file and the only format I have is this string copied from Windows registry. Is there a way to convert that? What I found is that I should open putty -> connection -> SSH -> auth -> browse but the Libraries/Documents directory is empty.